# Lyx: document cannot be opened

Tags: lyx

I am writing my very first serious Lyx document for end project of study. All was well and I was having fun until tonight when I tried to open it, it cannot be opened:

Error says:

> Doesn't respond.

What is going on? How can I fix this problem? I don't really want to start it over again. I have spent quite a few nights on it already.

Thanks

Comment: Check if your LyX is configured to make automatic backups and you have a backup file. In the worse case, make a copy of `yourfile.lyx` as `yourfile.txt` and open it with a text editor to see if all your text is still here.

Comment: Always keep backups. If you don't have one, you need a backup strategy. I know it is annoying to be told this when it may be too late, but sometimes it is, in fact, the only advice which is of any use at all. And if you are lucky this time, don't count on being so next time. Sooner or later, disks die. Even if other bad stuff doesn't happen first.

Comment: Hello, thanks for all responses, I am so sorry for my late response, I couldn't respond because I accidently created this post with the other user and I had to be wait the merge... So For the question of @Fran Unfortunatly I didn't make a backup already, However, I could make a copy of yourfile.lyx as yourfile.txt and I open it and then I found all texts in the text file, I could see my all project mix with the code of lyx, please do you have any idea how to recreate the project based on this text file ? Thanks.

Comment: @fahdijbeli I would try to make a "Hello word"  lyx file and then include between "Hello" and "word" chunks of the text of the damaged file and test in LyX. You must be careful of not break environments  during the copy & paste and using the same documents class with the same packages if your text include special commands.

Comment: Hello @Fran thanks for your response, could you check please my file http://www.filedropper.com/pfemed you could download it :),

Comment: @fahdijbeli  Delete the lines of code after the last paragraph "Au cours de ce travail, 9 variétés de citronnier on été collectées en provenance
 de différents régions présentées dans le tableau 5.1." and add these 3 LyX commands in 3 lines:  
`\end_layout` 
`\end_body` 
`\end_document` . Then,  save the text with the` .lyx` extension and it should be editable again by LyX.

Comment: Hello @Fran , yeah thats resolve my problem Thanks a lot :-).

Comment: @fahdijbeli You're welcome. BTW, do not use` \hspace{0.5cm}` ....`\newline` to format the paragraphs. Instead, use  some like `\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}\setlength{\parindent}{0.5cm}`in the preamble  and in the main screen  write the text and just press Enter to end  the paragraph.  On the other hand,  ... citations in plain text?!  If the reason is that you do not know  the alternatives (e.g. the  "insert citation button" in LyX,...) , download JabRef  and waste your time in learn how you use the JabRef database in LyX (i.e., what is LaTeX+BibTeX).

Comment: @Fran, yes thats work for using the `\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}\setlength{\parindent}{0.5cm}` it's more powrful :-), and okay for JabRef I am about to download it, Thank you again :-).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be about a corrupt .lyx-file (solved in comments).